# Retrieve column names using a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a list with 14 data frames, i want to retrieve the column names of each data frame with a for loop.

```
files_list <- list(data_04, data_05, data_06, data_07, data_08, data_09, data_010, data_011,
                   data_012, data_013, data_015, data_016, data_017, data_018)
```

Basically i want to avoid doing this with each data frame.

```
colnames(data_04)
```

Comment: `lapply(files_list, colnames)`

Comment: Try `lapply(files_list, names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may also use `sapply`

```
sapply(files_list, colnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` and extract column names from each dataframe.

```
lapply(files_list, colnames)
```

This can also be done with `purrr::map` similarly.

```
purrr::map(files_list, colnames)
```

As @Sotos suggested using `names` instead of `colnames` should also work for dataframes.